# NodeJS require multiple modules via index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node project that I am working on. It has multiple modules that need to be required throughout the project. Think ahead, I thought it would be a great idea to use `index.js` as a type of interface to access these different modules. Here is an example:

lib/FileA.js

```
var doStuff = function(){
        console.log("Hello");
};

module.exports = doStuff;
```

lib/FileB.js

```
var doThings = function(){
enter code here
};

module.exports = doThings;
```

lib/index.js

```
const A = require('./FileA');
const B = require('./FileB');

module.exports = {
    A: A,
    B: B
};
```

/Controller.js

```
const Modules = require('./lib');

console.log(Modules);
// This returns undefined??

console.log(Modules.A)
// This return undefined too
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**
Sorry. I was typing from memory. I have updated the code. I am basically calling `node Controller.js`.

Comment: `require('./lib');` will look for the `main` entry in `package.json` I thought? Does `require('./lib/index.js');` work?

Comment: How are you invoking `controller.js`, and what version of Node are you using?

Comment: I just noticed, in `FileA.js` and `FileB.js`, you declare `var function = ...`, which throws a `SyntaxError`, so you shouldn't even be getting to the `console.log()`s at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every thing looks fine to me be. other then the code of FileA and FileB

lib/FileA.js

```
var  doStuff=  function(){
        console.log("Hello");
};

module.exports = doStuff;
```

lib/FileB.js

```
var  doThings= function(){
// enter code here
};

module.exports = doThings;
```

lib/index.js

```
const A = require('./FileA');
const B = require('./FileB');

module.exports = {
    A: A,
    B: B
};
```

/Controller.js

```
const Modules = require('./lib');

console.log(Modules);
// will work fine
console.log(Modules.A)
// will work fine
```

folder structure

```
/lib
 -- index.js
 -- FileA.js
 -- FileB.js
/controller.js
```

And call .

**node controller.js**